# MonoDevelop: find Mono SDK in Options panel, but says 'missing SDK" on "New Solution" option

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

folks.
Here it is. Im trying to begin with Mono for Android. The thing is: i've downloaded and installed MonoDevelop and the SDKs.

In Options panel I have setted the SDKs path and MonoDevelop said "Ok, I found the SDKs" and shows the "green tick" above the field.

But..... when I try to make a New Solution from "File" menu, and choose "Mono For Android" option, it pops up a alert error "The Mono for Android SDK is required (...). Please install Mono for Android".

In my addin manager panel it shows "Mono for Android development" under "Mobile Development" menu. Is there any SDK or any settings I need to do to make MonoDevelop start a new Android Solution?
Here you can see some prin-screens:

[image]
http://a.yfrog.com/img740/6192/9l1e.png
[image]

Im using trial version: MonoDevelop 2.8.5.1
Thanks a lot for your help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Android SDK? This is probably what you are missing. Not being able to see the absolute path in your screenshot does not help.

But you need to get the Android SDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Hi, Cheesebaron. Thanks for your help. I cant say if I was missing something, but I just reinstall and everything worked fine.